# Simple.OData.Client returns no results

Tags: xamarin, odata

I trying to use Simple.OData.Client within PCL Xamarin.Forms project, but it doesn't return anything.

This is my code:

```
Simple.OData.Client.ODataClient clientOData = new Simple.OData.Client.ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

var cust = await clientOData.For("Customers").FindEntriesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is similar to what the library has in its integration tests (which pass). What do you mean by that it doesn't return anything? Does it fail? Returns an empty result?

Comment: This code works fine on a desktop project, after upgraded all Nuget packages, but not in Xamarin.Forms. It fails on .FindEntryAsync method. I think that a deadlock exception is thrown, but I don't know why.

Comment: This sounds familiar and usually happens if you use Wait or Result on async operations.

Comment: Solved! I've installed Simple.OData.V4.Client instead of V3 package and added V4Adapter.Reference(); statement, and now it works.

Comment: Good to hear! Congratulations